# Constant struct in Go

Tags: go

Why can't I create constant struct?

```
const FEED_TO_INSERT = quzx.RssFeed{ 0,
                    "",
                    "desc",
                    "www.some-site.com",
                    "upd_url",
                    "img_title",
                    "img_url",
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    100,
                    "alt_name",
                    1,
                    1,
                    1,
                    "test",
                    100,
                    100,
                    0 }
```

> .\rss_test.go:32: const initializer quzx.RssFeed literal is not a constant

Comment: Can you add the link to the answered question? It would be good to link back to the original question for duplicating.

Comment: Flagging to reopen. Asking if you can make a constant struct is different to asking about an array, even if the *answers* are similar.

Comment: Constant structs have the potential implementation issue that user may try to assign to a constant field, which is possibly the reason why they didn't implement this to start with.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Because Go does not support struct constants (emphasis mine)

> **There are boolean constants, rune constants, integer constants,
>   floating-point constants, complex constants, and string constants.**
>   Rune, integer, floating-point, and complex constants are collectively
>   called numeric constants.

Read more here: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants

Comment: Sad.  This is a handy language feature.

Answer (score 28):

A good workaround is to wrap it in a function.

```
func FEED_TO_INSERT() quzx.RssFeed {
    return quzx.RssFeed{ 0,
                    "",
                    "desc",
                    "www.some-site.com",
                    "upd_url",
                    "img_title",
                    "img_url",
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    100,
                    "alt_name",
                    1,
                    1,
                    1,
                    "test",
                    100,
                    100,
                    0 }
}
```

Note: Make sure that the function is always returning a new object(or copy).

Comment: You emulate something constant, which can not change and should be identical to itself, by "always returning a new object". Sounds strange.

Comment: This works functionally, but may have performance impact on memory & computation, unless go caches the function result. I wonder if go does do that compiler optimization.

Answer (score 23):

You should declare it as a var.

Go allows you to declare and initialize global variables at module scope.

Go does not have any concept of immutability. 'const' is not meant as a way to prevent variables from mutating or anything like that.

Comment: This is true (`const` in Go is closer to `#define` in C than to `readonly` in C#), but doesn't really explain why there can't be struct-like `const` values. They were probably excluded (along with array-like and map-like values) to simplify the compiler design.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare your struct fields as private and then create getter methods.

```golang
type ImmutableType struct {
  immutableField string
}

func (p ImmutableType) GetImmutableField() string {
  return p.immutableField
}
```

If you do this, the field itself will be inaccessible outside the module and will become sort of immutable.

However,

- this can only be done on the struct level, not when declaring a variable
- if you want to instantiate your struct outside of the module, you'll have to also create a constructor, which becomes kind of a mess since constructors are not really a commonly used practice in Go.

In order to "force" the use of your constructor, you might also declare your struct itself private, so it cannot be created as a composite literal without the private fields.

```golang
type immutableType struct {
  immutableField string
}

func (p immutableType) GetImmutableField() string {
  return p.immutableField
}

func CreateImmutableType(immutableField string) immutableType {
  return immutableType{
    immutableField: immutableField,
  }
}
```

TL;DR Go doesn't have immutability as a core concept, so implementing it requires a bunch of boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

As was said, Go does not support constant struct variables. This has a reason, compiler cannot ensure immutability of any struct (e.g. containing a pointer). Solution is rather simple: just use normal variable:

```
type Person struct {
    age int
}

var Luke = Person{10}
```

You can also use anonymous struct:

```
var Andrew = struct {
    age int
}{
    age: 13,
}
```

When you create this as a global variable, treat it as that - with care. The other recommendation is to use a function to return always a copy and that is the other extreme.